# Support of a Weil divisor equals to support of Cartier divisor?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, divisors-algebraic-geometry

Sorry for my bad English.

Let $X$ be locally fractional integral Noetherian scheme on which we can identify Weil divisor and Cartier divisor (cf. Hartshorne II.Prop.6.11).

If $D$ is a Cartier divisor, we define support of $D$ as

> Supp$D:=\{x\in X| D_x\neq 1\}$

where $D_x$ is stalk at $x$ of $D\in {\scr K}^*/{\scr O}^*_X$.

On the other hand, we can  think $D$ as a Weil divisor, so $D=\sum_{i} n_i Y_i$ where $Y_i$ are prime divisors and $n_i\in \mathbb{Z}\backslash \{0\}$.

Now Supp$D=\bigcup_i Y_i$?

Please help me, thanks.

Comment: Have you seen the proof of II Proposition 6.11 of Hartshorne's book? Maybe it helps

Comment: Yes it is. You should look at how you construct the weil divisor from cartier divisor, if x is a point of height 1, the coefficent of weil divisor at x is length(or in the simple case of smooth at codimension one valuation) of $D_x$ Now obvoiusly this vanish if $D_x=1$ and conversely if valuation of $D_x$ vanish it is an easy exercise in algebra to show that $D_x$ is a unit

Comment: I think hartshorne always assume that everything is smooth at codimension 1 for the theory of divisors

Answer (score 1):

The answer is positive. It suffices to first consider the case when $D\geq 0$, which follows from [EGAIV$_4$, 21.6.6.2] that $\mathrm{Supp}(\mathrm{cyc}(D))=\mathrm{Supp}(D)$ and the definition [EGAIV$_4$, 21.6.1]. Here $\mathrm{cyc}: \mathrm{Div}^+(X)\rightarrow \mathfrak{Z}^1(X)$ is the homomorphism from the monoid of effective Cartier divisors to the group of codimension-one cycles (Weil divisors).